# Trying to use PHP imap_open() with diff. linux interface(eth0:1, eth0:2). Any ideas?

Tags: php, linux, email, imap

I am trying to use imap_open() with different linux interfaces but I can't find a possible solution. Nginx seems to have a module (http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxMailCoreModule) for mail servers but I am on Apache + PHP.

cURL has something similar: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "eth0:1") but can't find anything for PHP imap.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot

Comment: This is really a question for Server Fault, I think; depending on what you actually want to do (you don't say...), load balancing and routing over multiple interfaces should be done by the OS TCP/IP stack, not by you manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do this. It sounds like you're trying to set the source IP address of the IMAP connection. While the application making the IMAP client connection *could* do this, there would almost never be a need to, and a couple of good reasons not to.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to proxy all traffic coming through the `php` command to a different network interface. All other ways would require modifying the source code because PHP's built-in IMAP library does not support this feature.

If you cURL's IMAP support isn't too limited for your purposes, you could also try that.